# wrong A4 pdf size

Tags: pdf, geometry, paper-size

I want to configure the A4 paper size in latex to the standard size, i.e. 8.27 x 11.69 in. Right now my generated pdf has size of 8.50 x 11.00 in
[image]

How do I get the right size so that I can print it out without dimensions being corrupted. I generate the pdf file by using LATEX->PDF option. My preamble setting is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.75cm, right=2.75cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: Use `a4paper` in the `geometry` option: `\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.75cm, right=2.75cm,a4paper]{geometry}`

Comment: Or pass `a4paper` to the document class.

Comment: @karlkoeller: That won't help.

Comment: @MartinSchröder It works for me with `report`

Comment: @Sigur your suggestion works. In my latex, the default paper is `letterpaper`, when I added a4paper in the 'geometry' i can get the 8.27x11.69 inches A4 size. Please make your comment as an answer so that i can approve it. THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `a4paper` in the `geometry` option by means of

```
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.75cm, right=2.75cm, a4paper]{geometry}
```